# How to create an entry_points with setuptools with a class method?

Tags: python, setuptools

If I wrote a function like this :

```
def my_function():
    # do something
```

I can create a command that run this function using :

```
entry_points = {
     'console_scripts': [
         'my_command = module:my_function',
     ],
 },
```

Suppose I have the following class:

```
class MyPackage:
    def __init__(self):
        # manage something with argparse and others ...

    def main(self):
        # do the job
```

Is there a way to use the main method of the class `MyPackage` or must I write a basic function ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe it can be a class method or a static method but not an instance
method.

```
class MyPackage:
    def __init__(self):
        # manage something with argparse and others ...

    @classmethod
    def main_classm(cls):
        # do the job

    @staticmethod
    def main_stat():
        # do the job

entry_points = {
     'console_scripts': [
         'command1 = module:MyPackage.main_classm',
         'command2 = module:MyPackage.main_stat',
     ],
},
```